# Undefined references when installing OpenCV on Raspberry Pi

Tags: opencv, raspberry-pi

I'm trying to install OpenCV on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model B running Buster (July 2019) using [this guide](https://www.learnopencv.com/install-opencv-4-on-raspberry-pi/). I eventually run into the following error after running the `make -j4` command.

```
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_add_8'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `__atomic_fetch_sub_8'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `__atomic_store_8'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `__atomic_load_8'
/usr/bin/ld: ../../lib/libopencv_core.so.4.1.1: undefined reference to `__atomic_compare_exchange_8'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/build.make:571: bin/opencv_test_core] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:1459:modules/core/CMakeFiles/opencv_test_core.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:163: all] Error 2
```

My CMake command is:

```
cmake -D CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=RELEASE \
            -D CMAKE_INSTALL_PREFIX=$cwd/installation/OpenCV-"$cvVersion" \
            -D INSTALL_C_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D INSTALL_PYTHON_EXAMPLES=ON \
            -D WITH_TBB=ON \
            -D WITH_V4L=ON \
            -D OPENCV_PYTHON3_INSTALL_PATH=$cwd/OpenCV-$cvVersion-py3/lib/python3.5/site-packages \
        -D WITH_QT=ON \
        -D WITH_OPENGL=ON \
        -D OPENCV_EXTRA_MODULES_PATH=../../opencv_contrib/modules \
        -D BUILD_EXAMPLES=ON ..
```

So far, I've run `make clean` and `make` to see if a single core installation might help. If it does I will update this post. If it doesn't however, does anyone know how to solve this error?

EDIT: After `make clean` and `make` the error still occurred

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This problem is also raised here 
https://github.com/opencv/opencv/issues/15192

As a workaround try to use cmake option: -DOPENCV_EXTRA_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS=-latomic

You can find an example script here https://gist.github.com/willprice/abe456f5f74aa95d7e0bb81d5a710b60

Edit: I had to call python with 
LD_PRELOAD=/usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libatomic.so.1.2.0 python3

in order to import cv2